# How to get value from an attribute in selenium RC in java?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have this code for xpath and html:

```
<a class="WatchButton inicon" rel="nofollow" data-productid="111124"> 

xpath=/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/a
```

How can I get the `data-productid` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `@data-productid` to the xpath expression:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/a/@data-productid
```

Note that the xpath expression you have is **very fragile** since it depends on a bunch of elements and their relevant positions. Try to rely on the element's attributes or one of it's containers - look for id and class attributes. For example:

```
//a[contains(@class, "WatchButton")]/@data-productid
```

This gets the first link anywhere on a page that contains `WatchButton` class and retrieves it's `data-productid` attribute value.

---

<sub>* Sharing the link to the web page or showing the complete HTML could help to provide you with a more reliable xpath expression.</sub>